# Identify helmets from LEGO Bionicle

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

I found these LEGO Bionicle helmets when looking through a box in my attic. I want to identify the corresponding sets.

[image]

Comment: Could you get a higher resolution picture with better lighting - especially for the second to last on the first row ?

Answer (score 8):

Top-left is [part 50931 "Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Vakama"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50931), which [appears in two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50931&in=S) in dark red.

[image: 50931]

Next to its right is [53584 "LegoBionicle Mask Ignika (Vezon)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53584). Judging from the colour, I'd say it's from [set 8764-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8764-1).

[image: 53584]

Next is [52806 "Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Matau"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=52806) from [set 8740-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8740-1).

[image: 52806]

Next, I cannot identify the green (lime green? bright green?) spiky one, but fellow user [Sander de Dycker](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/19372/sander-de-dycker) identified it as [57553pb01 "Bionicle Head, Barraki Ehlek with Marbled Lime Pattern"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57553pb01), in transparent green, which [appears in two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57553pb01&in=S).

[image: 57553pb01]

Next is [52818 "Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Onewa"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=52818) from [set 8739-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8739-1).

[image: 52818]

Next one is too dark in the photograph to tell apart any identifying details. But fellow user [Matthew Jensen](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/13390/matthew-jensen) thinks it might be [50927 "Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Whenua"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50927) from set [8738-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8738-1). It's difficult to be 100% sure without a better photograph, though.

[image: 50927]

Last one on the top row is [78180 "Bionicle Mask Jutlin with Black Top (Shapeshifted)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=78180) from [set 8691-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8691-1).

[image: 78180]

---

Bottom row. First is [part 50931 "Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Vakama"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50931) (same as top row) in dark green, from [set 8940-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8940-1).

Second one is [64786 "Bionicle Mask Suletu - Flexible Rubber"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=64786) from [set 8731-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8731-1)

[image: 64786]

Next is [45682 "Bionicle Mask Huna (Toa Metru)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=45682) which [appears in 7 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47308&in=S).

[image: 45682]

Next one is [46479 "Bionicle Mask Ruru (Toa Metru)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=46479) in dark blue, from [set 8940-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8940-1).

[image: 46470]

For the next one, I wasn't able to find any masks/heads in orange with brown on top. Fellow user Sander de Dycker pointed out that it's dark red with orange in the face, instead: [part 57531pb01 "Bionicle Mask Arthron with Orange Face"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57531pb01) from [set 8911-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8911-1).

[image: 57531pb01]

Last one in the bottom row is [78570 "Bionicle Mask Radiak with Black Top"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=78570) from [set 8947-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8947-1).

[image: 78570]

---

In general: Doing a reverse image search from a cropped portion of the photograph usually yields good results, but it's easier to do when the photograph is taken with a white background, good lighting to minimize shadows, and closer up (macro photography would help a lot). Unfortunately a carpet background doesn't help much, as happens with the black mask/head.

Otherwise, bricklink searches for "bionicle head" and "bionicle mask" with the advanced search option of filtering by colour do provide short lists of parts which are quick to look through. The downside is that one needs to know the exact lego colour of the part, which is not always an easy task (as happens with the bright green spiky one and the pearly orange one).

Comment: Second to last on the bottom row looks like [Dark Red Bionicle Mask Arthron with Orange Face](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57531pb01&idColor=59#T=C&C=59).

Comment: Fourth on the top row looks like [Trans-Green Bionicle Head, Barraki Ehlek with Marbled Lime Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57553pb01&idColor=20#T=C&C=20)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I've edited my answer with the information you provided. Thanks for identifying those elusive parts!

Comment: Sixth on top row appears to be [Bionicle Head, Toa Hordika Whenua](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50927&idColor=11&name=Black%20Bionicle%20Head,%20Toa%20Hordika%20Whenua&category=%5BBionicle%5D#T=C&C=11)